# How can I adjust this Flexbox layout based on multiple criteria?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
Current Layout
-------------------

 - Banner Row:Group
 -   Column 1: Label   Column 2: Input or Select  Column 3: Button or Link
 - EndGroup
 - Banner Row:Group
 -   Column 1: Label   Column 2: Input or Select  Column 3: Button or Link
 - EndGroup
 - Banner Row:Group
 -   Column 1: Label   Column 2: Input or Select  Column 3: Button or Link
 - EndGroup
```

- I would like Col1 (label) to be right justified, equal fixed widths
- I would like Col2 (input or select) to be same size, fixed width
- I would like Col3 (Button or Link) to be left justified
- I would like decreasing window width to wrap col component onto next line like at the same time for each column

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#box {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: wheat;
    display: flex;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-color: black;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    margin: 10px 50px;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 18px #888888;
}
#banner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #0099cc;
    border-radius: 500px;
    padding: 10px 50px 0 50px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
}
#banner-text {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.right {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
#box input[type="tel"], input[type="email"], select {
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
a:link {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    align-self: center;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}
.button {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px solid #0099cc;
    background-color: #0099cc;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
.button:hover {
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.button:disabled {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #666666;
}
textarea {
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
}
label {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.group {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="banner">
    <img
      src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2020/thank-you-public-health-workers-and-to-researchers-in-the-scientific-community-6753651837108753-law.gif"
      alt="Banner"
      width="300"
      height="92"
    />
    <h3>Header Text</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="input">Provider:</label>
    <select id="selected">
      <option value="opt1">Option #1</option>
    </select>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="input">Patient Email:</label>
    <input
      type="email"
      id="email"
      name="email"
      placeholder="user@domain.com"
    />
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Send Email" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="input">Patient Mobile Phone:</label>
    <input
      type="tel"
      id="sms"
      name="sms"
      placeholder="(123) 456-7890"
    />
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Send SMS Text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cycle4passion/9b430e52/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possibility for you. Based on what you were saying you wanted, it seemed to me that css grid was the better option.

So, I added css grid with `grid-template-columns: max-content max-content 1fr;` as the columns and it'll add new rows as you create them.

I made the wrapping divs (`.grid>div`) use `display: contents` although it isn't fully supported on all major browsers yet, the way to get around using that would be to just remove the wrapping divs as grid will take care of the rest anyway.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#box {
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: wheat;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-color: black;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  margin: 10px 50px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 18px #888888;
}

#banner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #0099cc;
  border-radius: 500px;
  padding: 10px 50px 0 50px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
}

#banner-text {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.right {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}

#box input[type="tel"],
input[type="email"],
select {
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0 10px;
  /*width: 200px;*/
}

a:link {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-self: center;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}

.button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #0099cc;
  background-color: #0099cc;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.button:hover {
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.button:disabled {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #666666;
}

textarea {
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content 1fr;
}
.grid>div {
  display: contents;
}

.grid>div>:first-child {
  justify-self: flex-end;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .grid>div>:first-child {
    justify-self: flex-start;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="banner">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2020/thank-you-public-health-workers-and-to-researchers-in-the-scientific-community-6753651837108753-law.gif" alt="Banner" width="300" height="92" />
    <h3>Header Text</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">

    <div>
      <label for="input">Provider:</label>
      <select id="selected">
        <option value="opt1">Option #1</option>
      </select>
      <a href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="input">Patient Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="user@domain.com" />
      <input type="button" class="button" value="Send Email" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="input">Patient Mobile Phone:</label>
      <input type="tel" id="sms" name="sms" placeholder="(123) 456-7890" />
      <input type="button" class="button" value="Send SMS Text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. Grid doesn't work I have to support ie11. Also it is not responsive (elements in each row need to drop into columns as screen width decreases to support small screen mobile.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you are going to get quite where you want with flex-box. It's not a tool to make columns and tables and grids. It's a tool to make the best arrangement when you have no idea the size of the container or the items. I'll add responsivity to the css grid as that's just a media query with a breakpoint.

Comment: @cycle: contrary to popular disinformation IE 11 supports (an older spec of) CSS Grid; as an example this four-part [CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-in-ie-debunking-common-ie-grid-misconceptions/). There are some issues with IE11's version, but much of the functionality is there.